# 2 stake pools using the same ticker name

Tags: stake-pool, staking, pool, name

we registered our pool on 2021-02-16 at 03:24:16. But unfortunately we noticed after our pool registration, that there was a second pool which has been registered with the same ticker 13 minutes later. It results in some confusion when users try to search for us in Daedalus or Yoroi to delegate their stakes.

I’ve read that when it comes to tickers attribution, we are going with a “a first take, first serve…” basic rule so obviously we are the most legitimate to use this ticker as we registered first, aren’t we ? I followed the recommendation by sending an e-mail to adapools at cardanians.io 1 to explain the situation but I would also be glad to have your recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'a first take, first serve' rule you mentioned is for the ITN (Incentivized Test Net) only.

Once registered, your Stakepool metadata including your ticker is inserted and stored in the [SMASH](https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-components/smash) (Stakepool Metadata Aggregation Server), an off-chain metadata server maintained by IOHK used by default by [Daedalus wallet](https://daedaluswallet.io/) or [Yoroi wallet](https://yoroi-wallet.com/) to load stake pool names and details.

So when ADA hodlers are looking for a pool to delegate their stakes by typing a name in the Daedalus or Yoroi search bar, it is in the SMASH database that they are looking at. Sending an email to adapools won't solve your problem.

There are a [few exceptions where IOHK will be able to remove a ticker from SMASH](https://docs.cardano.org/getting-started/operating-a-stake-pool/SMASH) (not the network). In short, if both of you don't meet these few exceptions, there's a good chance you will be sharing that same ticker unless one of the two pools changes it.

Comment: So let me ask a follow up question, if there are no rules to using the same ticker, what prevents people from piggybacking off of someone else's marketing work by using the same ticker? Seems like someone could easily copy logos and cause a lot of confusion to newcomers who wouldn't know how to check which one was legitimate. (Or I guess original might be a better word). Thanks!

Comment: Yes I had the same question.

Comment: Hello@Anton, the case you are referring to is one of those exceptions for IOHK to remove the pool from SMASH. it is called impersonation: stake pools that attempt to impersonate other individuals, groups, or organizations in a manner that misleads, confuses, or deceives others. For example, a successful stake pool called POOL being obviously impersonated by another called P00L (by linking to the same website).
Now in the case of the original question, it seems it was pure coincidence. You can have a look at this link docs.cardano.org/getting-started/operating-a-stake-pool/SMASH –